# iOS development. Checking for networking and redirect to the begining of the app

Tags: ios, networking

I am developing an app that should have similar functionalities as the game in the appStore Ace Card (now is called Casino). If you have your app in the background for a while or you lose your connection when you activate the game again this one starts from the beginning. If you still do not have a connection your application will not continue.

My app needs to retrieve some information from my server, and send some other information to the server, so if the device does not have a network connections or loses it there is no point to do anything or being in the middle of the app.

- How can I check for connection?
- How can I go back to the first ViewController and reset all its fields?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks hol, for correcting my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's Reachability examples. This is covered in full there and elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the name of the topic now I know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

As for the view controller ... that's entirely up to your design ... if are you using a `UINavigationController` use:

```
[navigationController popToRootViewController:NO];
```

and force a reset on that controller

Comment: Actually I am using simple UIViewControllers. I use some buttoms to make some modals from UIViewController to UIViewController.